# EaselJS animation inside the ticker

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I have a Sprite made in EaselJS:

```
var Hero = new createjs.Sprite(spritesheet, 'run');
Hero.die = function() {
        game.Ticker.removeAllEventListeners();
        Hero.gotoAndPlay('death');
});
stage.addChild(Hero);
```

Inside my ticker I have something like:

```
if(heroCollideBullet) Hero.die();
```

But I'm only seeing the first frame, the sprite its not getting updated.

Can someone explain how why is this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling `Ticker.removeAllListeners()`, which is removing your listener for `tick` that is calling `stage.update(evt)`. The `stage.update(evt)` call is required both to advance the Sprite, and to re-render the stage.

I'd generally caution strongly against using `removeAllListeners()`, since it can have unintended results (like this), and instead remove listeners individually.

Comment: if i dont remove the listener, my animation is stuck on frame 0, so no results

Comment: i found a solution to remove the tick listener from the tick() fn and add it to the stage, its this a good practice? game.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', CANVAS);